# Converting Text to specific date format in R

Tags: r, date, strptime

I have the following characters(sample):

```
>trial
[1] "9-5"  "7-5"  "13-3" "17-6"
```

And I want to convert them to **date format**(if possible) and become something like the following:

```
>trial
[1] Friday 9:00  Friday 7:00  Wednesday 13:00  Saturday 17:00
```

I am using the following code, which is not the desired result:

```
>strptime(trial,format="%k-%w")
[1] "2015-10-06 09:00:00 CEST" "2015-10-06 07:00:00 CEST"
[3] "2015-10-06 13:00:00 CEST" "2015-10-06 17:00:00 CEST"
```

My point is that I want to have date format for weekdays and hour. How can it be done?

Comment: something like ?`strftime(strptime(trial, format="%k-%w"), format="%A %H:%M")`

Comment: Remember that the the date is assumed to be today when it is not specified `"For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."`

Comment: Not sure why you're emphasizing "date format". If you want a date-class object, you cannot customize its display (unlike in Stata, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe i was not clear in the description. I don't need the format to be specifically like I described. What I want is having, for example, an `x` which is date format and when: `weekdays(x)` to have an output `"Monday" "Monday" "Friday" `... The same for the hour format.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I might do:

```
library(data.table) # for wday & tstrsplit

a_wk  <- Sys.Date()+1:7
wdays <- weekdays(a_wk)[ order(wday(a_wk)) ]
# "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"

data.table(trial)[,tstrsplit(trial, "-", type.convert=TRUE)][, 
  paste0(wdays[V2 + 1], " ", V1, ":00")
]
# "Friday 9:00"     "Friday 7:00"     "Wednesday 13:00" "Saturday 17:00"
```

The `+ 1` is needed because the `wday` function takes Sunday as day 1; while the OP uses Monday.

**Comments.** It could be written more concisely (only invoking `trial` once) as

```
setDT(tstrsplit(trial, "-", type.convert=TRUE))[, 
  paste0(wdays[V2 + 1], " ", V1, ":00")
]
```

You can see how this works by having a look at the intermediate result:

```
data.table(trial)[,tstrsplit(trial, "-", type.convert=TRUE)]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  9  5
# 2:  7  5
# 3: 13  3
# 4: 17  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
paste(weekdays((as.Date("1970-01-01")+4)+0:7)[as.numeric(sub(".*-(\\d+)", "\\1", trial))], sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1:00", trial))
[1] "Friday 9:00"     "Friday 7:00"     "Wednesday 13:00"
[4] "Saturday 17:00"
```

Or to explain what is going on I'll show it in intermediate steps:

```
#1. starting vector
trial <- c("9-5",  "7-5",  "13-3", "17-6")

#2. get the hour and add ":00" to the values
hr <- sub("(\\d+).*", "\\1:00", trial)

#3. get the day of the week as a number
d <- as.numeric(sub(".*-(\\d+)", "\\1", trial))

#4. pick a week with a Monday date that you know and add 6 days (I use The first Monday after the origin). Subset with 'd'
day_vector <- weekdays((as.Date("1970-01-01")+4)+0:7)[d]

#5. paste day and hour together
paste(day_vector, hr)

[1] "Friday 9:00"     "Friday 7:00"     "Wednesday 13:00"
[4] "Saturday 17:00"
```